# Date formatting in VB 2008 and MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, formatting

I have some problem about the date formatting in vb 2008 and MySQL server.
I want to have a textbox that inputs date that accepts this kind of format dd-mm-yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy then converts it to mysql date format yyyy-mm-dd.

As of to date, I don't have any idea how to start this kind of date formatting but I'm thinking to have it in a module.

Any ideas are much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The users have tendencies to input dates in various format such as dd-MM-yyyy, dd/M/yyyy, d.MM.yyyy etc. *Although we can curb them using the validators, regex(es) etc.* but without the use of any regex, validators and plugins we can use the following approach to validate and convert a date passed as a string in following format:

```
day[separator]month[separator]year
```

where day can be in `d` or `dd` (3, 03),
month can be `M` or `MM` (7, 07),
year  can be `yy` or `yyyy` (15, 2015) and
separator can be `[space]`, `/`, `.` or `-`

and can be in mixed formats such as
`dd-MM-YYYY`, `dd/MM/YYYY`, `dd.MM.YYYY`, `dd MM yyyy`, `d-M-YY`, `d/M/YY`, `d.M.YY`, `d M yy`, `d-MM-YYYY`, `dd/M/YYYY`, `dd.MM.YY` etc.

This function takes date as a string parameter in any of the above formats and validates and return a date in `yyyy-MM-dd`. It checks for leap year and takes 1970 as the base to check to convert from `yy` to `yyyy` format.

```
Public Function DMYtoYMD(stDate As String) As String
    Dim blValidDate As Boolean = True
    While stDate.Contains("  ")
        stDate = stDate.Replace("  ", " ")
    End While
    stDate = stDate.Trim.Replace(" ", "-").Replace("/", "-").Replace(".", "-")
    Dim stFinalDate As String = ""
    If stDate.Length > 0 Then
        Dim mc As String() = stDate.Split(CChar("-"))
        Dim inDay As Integer = CInt(mc(0))
        Dim inMonth As Integer = 0
        If IsNumeric(mc(1)) Then
            inMonth = CInt(mc(1))
        Else
            For inMonthNo As Integer = 1 To 13
                If inMonthNo = 13 Then
                    inMonth = 0
                    blValidDate = False
                    Return ""
                ElseIf MonthName(inMonthNo, True).ToLower = mc(1).ToLower.Substring(0, 3) Then
                    inMonth = inMonthNo
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        Dim inYear As Integer = Math.Abs(CInt(mc(2)))
        stFinalDate = ""
        If inYear < 100 Then
            'use above condition to convert 0 (i.e. 2000) to current year to 20xx and all others to 19xx
            'If inYear >= (CInt(Format(Today, "yy")) + 1) Then

            'use this condition to convert all yy year above 70 to 19xx and all others to 20xx
            If inYear > 70 Then
                inYear += 1900
            Else
                inYear += 2000
            End If

        'ignoring year from 101 to 999 (as per my specific requirement for the project). valid dates are to be from 1900 or above
        ElseIf inYear < 1900 Then '101 to 999
            stFinalDate = ""
            blValidDate = False
        End If
        If (inMonth < 1 OrElse inMonth > 12) Then
            stFinalDate = ""
            blValidDate = False
        ElseIf (inDay < 1 OrElse inDay > 31) Then
            stFinalDate = ""
            blValidDate = False
        ElseIf ((inMonth = 4 OrElse inMonth = 6 OrElse inMonth = 9 OrElse inMonth = 11) AndAlso inDay = 31) Then
            stFinalDate = ""
            blValidDate = False
        ElseIf (inMonth = 2) Then
            Dim isleap As Boolean = (inYear Mod 4 = 0 AndAlso (inYear Mod 100 <> 0 OrElse inYear Mod 400 = 0))
            If (inDay > 29 OrElse (inDay = 29 AndAlso Not isleap)) Then
                stFinalDate = ""
                blValidDate = False
            End If
        End If
        If blValidDate Then
            stFinalDate = CStr(New Date(inYear, inMonth, inDay))
            If Not IsDate(stFinalDate) Then
                stFinalDate = ""
            Else
                stFinalDate = Format(New Date(inYear, inMonth, inDay), "yyyy-MM-dd")
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Return stFinalDate
End Function
```

You can simply call it as

```
Dim dtDate As String = ""
dtDate = DMYtoYMD(TextBox1.Text) 'or as Class1.DMYtoYDM as per your code structure
```

This function returns a zero length string if the input date is not valid. It can further be modified to include `MMM` or `MMMM` formats to converts to `MM` and also check for `MM-dd-yyyy` or other input formats as per your requirements.